# How to pass a dynamic variable in Expressjs to all Pug templates?

Tags: express, pug

How would I pass a dynamic variable in app.js to all my Pug template files?

Comment: Please check https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Javascript objects `app.locals`,`res.locals` can solve your problem.

The `app.locals` object is a JavaScript object, and its properties are local variables within the application.

```
app.locals.title = 'My App';
```

`res.locals` properties that are valid only for the lifetime of the request. When you handle the route where you have a res object, you won't have an app object there and vice-versa for app.locals.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   res.locals.user = req.user || null;
   next();
});
```

You can access local variables in templates rendered, this is useful for providing helper functions to templates, as well as app-level data. Locals are available in middleware via `req.app.locals` (see [req.app](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.app))

You can acces the objects in pug this way : 
    html
    body
        h1 Hello World!

```
    if user != null
        p Hi there, #{user}!
    else
        p Hi there, unknown person!
```